# Why would anyone need TensorFlow's IdentityReader?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I saw that TF 1.0 has a new data reader called IdentityReader. It's described as "A Reader that outputs the queued work as both the key and value."

As I understand, it'll just outputs a same piece of information twice, once as key and once as value? In what scenario would I need something like that? It'd be great if you could give me a concrete example. Thanks a lot!